# Generic Factory with type parameter

Tags: c#

I have the following situation.

My Factory class needs to create appropriate Strategy objects based on the input string argument to the CreateStrategy function.

Strategy1, Strategy2 etc are all derived from a common StrategyBase class. However each strategy has a different Validation mechanism which is the type parameter to the Factory class. However, the StrategyValidators are not of any common type and have different interfaces.

Therefore, in the below code, I am unable to specify any common constraint on the StrategyValidator type.

I am new to C# and hence not sure if there exists any mechanism to get over this design issue. Please suggest

```
public class Factory
{
    //Create the appropriate Concrete Implementation class based on the type
    public static StrategyBase CreateStrategy<StrategyValidator>(String Type)
    {
        StrategyBase EnumImp = null;

        // WMI based implementation
        if (Type == "Type1")
        {
            s = Strategy1<StrategyValidator>.Instance;
        }
        else if (Type = "Type2")
        {
            s = Strategy2<StrategyValidator>.Instance;
        }
        return s;
    }

    private StrategyBase s;
}
```

Here's the intended usage

```
Factory f = new Factory(); 

f.CreateStrategy<WMIValidator>("WMI");
f.CreateStrategy<ABCDValidator>("ABCD");
```

where `WMIValidator` and `ABCDValidator` are unrelated types, but the actual classes created by `CreateStrategy` function are related in a hierarchy e.g. having a common base `StrategyBase`

Here is a sample code to illustrate the issue

```
namespace TestCSharp
{
    public interface IStrategy
    {
    };

    public interface S1 : IStrategy
    {
        void f1();
        void f2();
    };

    public class S1Concrete : S1
    {
        public void f1() { }
        public void f2() { }
    }

    public interface S2 : IStrategy
    {
        void f3();
        void f4();
    };

    public class S2Concrete : S2
    {
        public void f3() { }
        public void f4() { }
    };

    public interface ProductBase
    {
    };

    class Product1<T> : ProductBase where T : S1
    {
    };

    class Product2<T> : ProductBase where T : S2
    {
    };

    public class Factory
    {
        public ProductBase Create<T>(String Type)
        {
            if (Type == "P1")
                return new Product1<T>();
            else if (Type == "P2")
                return new Product2<T>();
        }
    };

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Factory f = new Factory();
            ProductBase s = f.Create<S1Concrete>("Type1");
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is

> The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type
>   or method 'TestCSharp.Product1'. There is no boxing conversion or
>   type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'TestCSharp.S1'.

Comment: im a little confused as what your intent is, can you please add in some code of how you would like to use the factory?

Comment: I would like to pass in different validation types associated with different Strategy objects. The CreateStrategy just helps me to instantiate the appropriate Strategy object with the user specified validation class

Comment: And since the Strategies work with completely different mechanisms to achieve the same goal, their validations are unique and have no commonality, in general

Comment: Im particularly intetrested to see usage code as Im not too sure why you have the generic at the class level here rather than a method level. On a side note perhaps their commonality is the fact that they are a strategy?

Comment: @Chubsdad I don't understand. If you can edit `ABCDValidator` and `WMIValidator` can't you simply give them a common ancestor class/interface, even if empty, then use it as a constraint?

Comment: @Eve: I posted a sample code to illustrate the issue.

Comment: @Luke McGregor: Pls check the sample code and intended usage

Comment: @Chubsdad eves answer is exactly what I would suggest for the factory class. I also like what shes suggesting with the IStrategy interface,  and would go further to say that even if you don't have a shared method for a strategy you should still use a marker interface (blank interface) so that we can restrict strategies.

Comment: @Luke McGregor: I would like Product1 and Product2 classes to have different constraints on the Strategy e.g. S1 and S2 respectively instead of IStrategy. But I want to create these Product Classes through a common Factory function

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your scenario fully but as far as I can tell the factory pattern you're using would have to instantiate products using reflection. This is a little ugly because it doesn't give the consumer any hints about what strategy types can be used with a given product name.

```
public class Factory
{
    public ProductBase Create<T>(string name)
    {
        Type type;
        switch (name)
        {
            case "P1":
                type = typeof (Product1<>);
                break;
            case "P2":
                type = typeof (Product2<>);
                break;
            case "P3":
                type = typeof (Product3<>);
                break;
            default:
                return null;
        }
        type = type.MakeGenericType(typeof (T));
        return (ProductBase) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer in this case is, it **depends on what you want `Product` and `Strategy` to do**. What you seem to be trying to do is splitting your logic in two branches. Then you want to couple it again by using generics, but as you can notice, it won't work.

Consider a scenario, similar to yours above -- But where each class implementing `IStrategy` has one instead of two methods which does side effect (i.e. print a string). You use generics when the range of types allowed have something in common. In the case I just mentioned, both have a method returning void and accepting no parameters; so we can add a method to `IStrategy`, for instance:

```
public interface IStrategy
{
    void ExecuteLogic();
};

public class S1 : IStrategy
{
    public void ExecuteLogic()
    {
        OneMethod();
    }

    void OneMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
};

public class S2 : IStrategy
{
    public void ExecuteLogic()
    {
        TotallyDifferentMethod();
    }

    void TotallyDifferentMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("World");
    }
};
```

Now, you also said that `Strategy1` and `Strategy2` have a different validation mechanism. However, it seems to me that you use them in the same method and context (and thus the same parameters and variables), so there must be something that makes them similar. Still, having defined `IStrategy` in the way we require, we can just use that as a constraint for `Create<T>`. So, `Factory` becomes:

```
public class Factory
{
    public ProductBase Create<T>(String Type) where T : IStrategy
    {
        if (Type == "P1")
            return new Product1<T>();
        else if (Type == "P2")
            return new Product2<T>();
        return null;
    }
};
```

But there's still one case. If you don't want `Product1` to be called with `S2` as a generic type, or `Product2` to have `S1` as its generic, then why using generics in the first place? You could easily couple the products with their relative strategies and also simplify the code remarkably.

In case I missed something (or the entire question) please leave a comment and I'll try to adapt my answer.

**EDIT**: since now you've redefined your example and used `S1` and `S2` as interfaces, I can see what you mean. A way would be defining multiple generic types and constraints for `Factory.Create`. Example:

```
public ProductBase Create<T1, T2>(String Type) where T1 : S1 where T2 : S2
```

It would be impossible otherwise, as you properly stated, because there's no common ancestor of `S1` and `S2` which can be accepted by your `Product` classes.

Comment: In my case, even if I have a common function ExecuteLogic, it would accept different arguments for each strategy class. Also please check in the latest code post, about the constraints on Product1 and Product2 which I want to be S1 and S2 respectively and not IStrategy

Comment: @Chubsdad i would say in this case you would simply remove the ExecuteLogic method from your IStrategy (so that its empty) but keep having the IStrategy as a decoration on the class to show that it IS a strategy. This improves readability and allows us to be typesafeer(?) with our stratgies.

Comment: @Chubsdad As the above commenter said, if `Product1` is constrained to `S1` and `Product2` to `S2`, I see no case in which using generics would produce alternatives (even if it was possible) to coupling the products with their respective strategies. It would also save you the hassle of using `IStrategy` as an interface since, as you've said, different strategies have different signatures. You can just put the whole logic in the products.

Comment: In my case S1 and S2 are interfaces and I can have different strategies from these interfaces and configure my product classes. This generates alternatives for combining products with strategies

Comment: class Product1<T> : ProductBase where T : S1, new()
    {
        void g()
        {
            T t = new T();
            t.f1();
        }
    };

Comment: In the above function 'g', if I add constraint as 'IStrategy' instead of 'S1', then I can't use 't.f1()'

Comment: @Chubsdad I've edited my post. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: How would the usage look like now? f.Create<S1Concrete, S2Concrete>("Type1");? Is there a way to avoid specifying S2Concrete above?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the function to take StrategyValidator as type.

From

```
public static StrategyBase CreateStrategy<StrategyValidator>(String Type)
```

To

```
public static StrategyBase CreateStrategy<T>(String Type) where T:StrategyValidator
```

To answer you question, You cannot avoid conditional checks.

To simplify the code can move the different combinations ("Type1", "Type2" , etc) to either `dictionary` or to the configuration if you use [`Dependency Injection`](http://objectview.wordpress.com/tag/strategy-pattern/), and then can you reflection.

Example.

```
    if (!dict.ContainsKey(key)) 
       throw New InvalidArgumentException();

    StrategyBase EnumImp = null;

    var instance = dict[key].MakeGenericType(typeOf(type)).GetProperty("Instance",  BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public ));   //dict is Dictionary<string, Type>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered overloading the Create<> function?  I don't have VisualStudio handy right now, but would the following code work for your situation?

```
namespace ... {
    // ... other code here...

    public class Factory {
        public Product1<T> Create<T>() where T : S1 {
            return new Product1<T>();
        }
        public Product2<T> Create<T>() where T : S2 {
            return new Product2<T>();
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Factory f = new Factory();
            ProductBase s = f.Create<S1Concrete>();
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally, you may wish to move your type constraints to a lower level.  Consider writing an abstract base ProductBase class (that inherits from an `IProductBase` interface?) as follows:

```
class ProductBase<T> : IProductBase where T : IStrategy { }
```

This may help to alleviate some of your headaches.