# Generic Type Detection

Tags: c#, c++

What's the equivalent of the following in C#?

```
template<class T>
struct S
{
   typedef T MyType;
};
```

Comment: C# generics and C++ templates are not the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generics and templates are different beasts. There is no equivalent.

Comment: This is the shortest answer I've ever posted on SO!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a disconnect between the C++ code you used and what can be done in C#.  It would help if you might explain what you're trying to accomplish with this code.  With no additional information, it looks like you just need to reference the generic type parameter.

```
public struct S<MyType> {
    private MyType value;
    // ... more stuff here...

    public MyType Value {
        get {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to beat my head around a design issue I posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270820/generic-factory-with-type-parameter

Comment: I'll respond in that thread (just to keep the comments relevant to the issue).